# Create Coverflow in Tablet Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, effect, coverflow

I want to create an app that use coverflow (please see video [HoneyComb](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAXm0-HA8O8&feature=BFa&list=PLEB1B3343FF46F141&lf=results_main) ). At 0:43, this effect is really cool. Does anyone have source code or help me to create it?

Answer (score 2):

here is a link

```
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html
```

u can use this..source code is also there....

Comment: I have used this sample. It displays is not the same with my requirements. It's difficult to find out the coverflow source code on android